# Connecting QField to my Garmin

Tags: qfield, garmin

I am using QField for field work this summer and I know that qfield should be able to connect to an external GPS. We were hoping to use the Garmin GPSMAP 66i. However, I haven't been able to connect them. Using the garmin specific app I was able to connect the two devices, however QField isn't using that GPS info and it can't see the Garmin. Anybody know anything about this?

Comment: can you see if GNSS is available after pairing Using an external GNSS Receiver https://docs.qfield.org/how-to/gnss/#using-an-external-gnss-receiver

Comment: it might be also useful to know the device (android/ios version)

Comment: Ive tried using the GNSS receiver, but it doesnt see the garmin either. I am using a samsung s8 tablet, so android.

Comment: this info from Garmin might help you https://support.garmin.com/en-CA/?faq=Mi8TKRtjWe6Cp4hwKvwFH7

Answer (score 0):

I have Garmin GLO. It appears to replace the internal GPS feed when I use the Internal GPS device in Qfield for iPad. (I turned off cellular and WiFi service for the test.) However, H accuracy is limited to 5 meters, probably by iOS. Qfield for iPad is not compatible with Bluetooth connected GPS receivers. I assume that this is a statement that a direct connection via Bluetooth is not allowed. TCP connections are allowed. I have been unable to find an App that facilitates the TCP connection for the Garmin GLO although there are apps that work for the Dual XGPS150, for example. My questions:

1. Has anyone seen an app that will facilitate a tcp connection between the Bluetooth Garmin GLO and Qfield?
2. Is there a reference that I can read to build my own data handler between the Garmin GLO and Qfield via tcp?